# Having problems with a dropdown list (hover) CSS HTML5

Tags: css, html

I'm having a problem with a dropdown list. Here is the HTML code I got.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd6nG.png

```
<nav>
    <a href="index.php"> Hjem </a>

    <ul>
        <li class="nav_link">
            <a onclick="extern_link_warning()" class="dropdown_hover" 
                   href="http://bbc.com">Innleveringer</a>
            <ul class="preview_box">
                <li>
                    <a onclick="extern_link_warning()" href="http://bbc.com">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="link2.html">Link 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=ommeg"> Om meg </a></li>

        <!-- Kun admin brukere ser disse sidene: -->

        <?php
            if ($isLoggedIn){
                echo '<li><a href="index.php?ap=admin"> Admin </a></li>';
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My CSS code for the dropdown:

```
.preview_box {
    display: none;
}

a:hover + .preview_box,.preview_box:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

The code above works, but the problem is that I want the ".preview_box" to appear when hovering a ".nav_link" tag instead of an "a" tag, but I can't get it to work. This is what I've tried:

```
.nav_link:hover + .preview_box, .preview_box:hover {

}

.nav_link:hover + .nav_link .preview_box, .nav_link .preview_box:hover {

}
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: Your `<li>` tags are not closed properly. They're missing closing brackets.

Comment: It seems you are not closing your tags, close `<li>` tags and it will work fine.

Comment: edited the code now, but I guess the content of .preview_box doesn't matter? I just want the .preview_box to appear when hovering .nav_link. any ideas? :)

Comment: I don´t see any problems... https://jsfiddle.net/j0731nfx/ can you please provide a jsfiddle with the issue?.

Comment: @Alex I've added a link to a screenshot above. I want to hover a .nav_link area, instead of a:hover. this is because if I use a:hover then the .preview_box would disappear before I could reach it with my mouse pointer (when moving the mouse from the link to the #preview_box it would disappear). This would not happen in the jsfiddle you made, but in my code I've added some extra styling. Anyway, this is what I want: https://jsfiddle.net/j0731nfx/3/

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the fact that it was solved, instead accept the answer that helped you the most. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after reading and reading your questions I think what you want is when you hover the `li` with the class `nav_link`you want to appear the `.preview-box` instead of hovering the anchor inside it...

Well, this should fix the problem...

```
.nav_link:hover .preview_box {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I see now why it could be difficult to understand, but you are right that's what I wanted. It was much easier than I though. Thanks!